# Install PHP in Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, php7

I am new in Linux Mint. I installed Linux Mint 19.1. Now I would like to install PHP7.2 in Linux Mint.

I found a way in [this](https://linux4one.com/how-to-install-php-7-2-on-linux-mint-19/?fbclid=IwAR2CilOznhpiQ5LwspLVcf68kGEE-XFMnp1FJVx9JD_9GxuYUjaEkG1lpq8) tutorial  and another way in [this](https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/) tutorial. I got another way in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_30P7up2jA) tutorial.

Which one should I follow ? Which is the correct way ?

Comment: all should work, but I would use the first one because it specifically says Linux Mint 19 and specifically installs PHP7.2